# What's the most efficient way from raw pixels to a PixelBuffer?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgimage, cvpixelbuffer

I'm receiving raw pixels of an image and successfully transforming them into a CGImage with the following function:

```
func imageFromTexturePixels(raw: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, w: Int, h: Int) -> CGImage? {
    // 4 bytes(rgba channels) for each pixel
    let bytesPerPixel: Int = 4
    // (8 bits per each channel)
    let bitsPerComponent: Int = 8

    let bitsPerPixel = bytesPerPixel * bitsPerComponent
    // channels in each row (width)
    let bytesPerRow: Int = w * bytesPerPixel

    let cfData = CFDataCreate(nil, raw, w * h * bytesPerPixel)

    let cgDataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: cfData!)!

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue)

    let image: CGImage! = CGImage(width: w,
                                  height: h,
                                  bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
                                  bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
                                  bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                  space: deviceColorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                                  provider: cgDataProvider,
                                  decode: nil,
                                  shouldInterpolate: false,
                                  intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

    return image
  }
```

What I really want in the end is a PixelBuffer, so I'm transforming that image into a pixelbuffer using [this extension](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/CoreMLHelpers/CGImage%2BCVPixelBuffer.swift).

Although all this works, it looks a bit inefficient and I'd like to know how to transform the raw pixels directly into a CVPixelBuffer, without converting them into a CGImage before.